# improve jquery accordion and remove bug

Tags: jquery, css, accordion

I have attempted to extend on an accordion for a SharePoint FAQ and I have almost working but wont to see if there is a more effective way to complete.
Please forgive me if this seems very simple, I have only just started jQuery and still rapping my head around this awesome framework.

the text fades in and out OK. was thinking of a slidein/slide out effect but that's something can work on latter.

there is an issue with the CSS I believe as the rows jump down when the text fadesIn.

Also notice that if you leave the bottom on the text does not fade out and when you mouseenter it will fade out and in. With the code I have it makes sense but not sure of better way to do it.

Really appreciate all assistance and/or advice. This site has been so helpful with my development work.

here is a link to the code [link to working example](http://etech-accordion.azurewebsites.net/)

**HTML**

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="accordion.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="StyleSheet.css">    
        <title>FADE</title>
    </head>
<body>
    <ul style="width:100%" class="accordion">
        <li class="accordion-item">
            <div class="accordion-header">Audit</div>
            <div  class="accordion-description">timelines, what &amp; who is involved</div>
            <div  class="accordion-content" style="display: none;">
                <div>Not sure what but it involves the world and the aliens....</div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="accordion-item">
            <div  class="accordion-header">Archiving</div>
            <div  class="accordion-description">how to/when to/what to archive</div>
            <div  class="accordion-content" style="display: none;">
                <div>Archive everything, no such thing as to many backups</div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="accordion-item">
            <div  class="accordion-header">Annual leave</div>
            <div  class="accordion-description">check how much annual leave you have and/or are entitled to, where to find forms</div>
            <div  class="accordion-content" style="display: none;">
                <div>Forms are awesome and in the intranet</div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="accordion-item">
            <div  class="accordion-header">Accommodation</div>
            <div  class="accordion-description">how do I book accommodation</div>
            <div  class="accordion-content" style="display: none;">
                <div>wotif or sweet talk someone to do it for you</div>
             </div>
         </li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
margin: auto;
width: 960px;
padding: 10px;
}

ul.accordion {
    list-style:none;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
.accordion-item {
    border-top:1px solid #ccc;
}
.accordion-header {
    font-size:1.2em;
    font-weight:bold;
    cursor:pointer;
    padding-top:10px;
}
.accordion-description {
    bottom: 25px;
    font-style: italic;
    left: 300px;
    margin-bottom: -12px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: right;
    width: 600px;
}
.accordion-header:hover {
    background:#efefef;
}
.accordion-header.expanded {
    background:#dfdfdf;
}
.accordion-content {
    padding:20px;
}
.expand-all,
.collapse-all {
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    padding:5px 10px;
}
.expand-all:hover,
.collapse-all:hover {
    background:#efefef;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
function accordionLoad() {

    $(".accordion-header").removeClass("expanded");
    $(".accordion-content").hide();

    $(".accordion-header").bind("click", function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("expanded");
        $(this).siblings(".accordion-content").slideToggle();
    })

    $('.accordion-description').hide();
    $('.accordion-item').on('mouseenter', function ()
    {
        // $(this).next().siblings
        $('.accordion-description').fadeOut();
        $(this).find('.accordion-description').fadeIn();

    });

    $(".expand-all").bind("click",function(){
        $(this).siblings(".accordion").find(".accordion-content").slideDown();
        $(this).siblings(".accordion").find(".accordion-header").addClass("expanded");
    })

    $(".collapse-all").bind("click",function(){
        $(this).siblings(".accordion").find(".accordion-content").slideUp();
        $(this).siblings(".accordion").find(".accordion-header").removeClass("expanded");
    })
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    accordionLoad();
});
```

Comment: You should post your code.

Comment: Try using CSS to do this

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with css ([**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/YK94p/6/)). Because it's a simple hover you don't really need jQuery. You can also add additional CSS3 transitions for the fade-in effect.

Added the hover on the item element:

```
.accordion-item:hover .accordion-description {
    -transition: opacity .7s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: opacity .7s ease-in-out;
   -webkit-transition: opacity .7s ease-in-out;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility:visible; 
}
```

Put the description before the header element because of `float: right`

```
<div  class="accordion-description">timelines, what &amp; who is involved</div>
<div class="accordion-header">Audit</div>
```

Changed some styles on the description element and set it to invisible by default:

```
.accordion-description {
   -transition: opacity .7s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: opacity .7s ease-in-out;
   -webkit-transition: opacity .7s ease-in-out;
    opacity: 0; 
    visibility:hidden; 
    font-style: italic;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Removed the mouseenter event of the item element:

```
function accordionLoad() {

    $(".accordion-header").removeClass("expanded");
    $(".accordion-content").hide();

    $(".accordion-header").bind("click", function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("expanded");
        $(this).siblings(".accordion-content").slideToggle();
    })

    $(".expand-all").bind("click",function(){
        $(this).siblings(".accordion").find(".accordion-content").slideDown();
        $(this).siblings(".accordion").find(".accordion-header").addClass("expanded");
    })

    $(".collapse-all").bind("click",function(){
        $(this).siblings(".accordion").find(".accordion-content").slideUp();
        $(this).siblings(".accordion").find(".accordion-header").removeClass("expanded");
    })
}
```